# libQt5Core.so.5 and Qt_5.6 not found inside docker container

Tags: linux, postgresql, qt, docker, qt5

We are trying to run a QT terminal application(interacting with a separate Postgres container QPSQL) inside a Ubuntu:Xenial docker container and to our knowledge we've fulfilled shared libraries:

> - 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libQt5Sql.so.5]
> - 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libQt5Core.so.5]
> - 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
> - 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
> - 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
> - 0x000000000000000f (RPATH)              Library rpath: [$ORIGIN:/home/adminiot/Qt5.6.0/5.6/gcc_64/lib]
>
> also provided sqldriver in /bin/sqldrivers

But its showing below error

> root@338d3f8000e2:/bin# ./Database
>
> ./Database: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Sql.so.5: version `Qt_5'
>   not found (required by ./Database)
>
> ./Database: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version
>   `Qt_5.6' not found (required by ./Database)
>
> ./Database: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5'
>   not found (required by ./Database)

P.S: If we try to execute the binary in Ubuntu, it works without a hassle and we're using QT release 5.6.0.

Comment: one more thing we  install  "sudo apt-get install qt5-default" inside docker container but still it is showing same error

Comment: anyone ans please

Comment: Can you edit the question to include your Dockerfile?

Comment: No problem David  we resolved this issue...

Comment: I am facing same issue ,kindly guide how you menage to resolve it.

Comment: taimur we can put your ".so" file in this path  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/